# Customize 3D environment for Assistant 2 Simulator [dji-sdk]

Tags: dji-sdk

At the very end of the DJI Simulator Tutorial it says this:
This demo is a simple demonstration of using DJISimulator, to have a better user experience, you can create a 3D simulated environment using 3D game engine like Unity3Dto show the simulated data and aircraft flight behavious inside your mobile application (Like the Flight Simulator in DJI Go app)!

I have been looking for a way to integrate a custom 3D model/environment objects into the simulation environment, but there does not seem to be a way. I can´t find any forum posts in regard to this either.

Does anyone have experience doing something like this or can point me in the direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is not any sample integrating a custom 3D mode.
But there are some states such as 'roll','yaw','pitch', etc in DJISimulatotState.
It is helpful to build another customized simulator using 3D game engine.
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Simulator/DJISimulator_DJISimulatorState.html#djisimulator_djisimulatorstate